# Streaming microphone from windows 10 to Linux using Pulseaudi

Tags: linux, networking, windows-10, streaming, microphone

I have a microphone on my windows 10 and a speaker on my Linux:
When I talk to mic, I want to hear it live on Linux over Network by usning PulseAudio.

I am a beginner with linux. I will be Thanksfull if someone could slove my problem.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have installed Pulseaudio on Windows as well, have a look at the [Tunnel source and sink modules](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/#index14h3) and the [RTP/SDP/SAP Transport modules](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/#index7h2) of Pulseaudio.

Step-by-step instructions should be available via google or in other questions.

Comment: yes i already have installed pulseaudio on Windows, but as I said I am totally a beginner with linux ... It would be super cool if you could explain it more. Thanks :)

Comment: i actuelly can play a wav music on windows with following code and hear it on linux : "c:\pulseaudio\bin\paplay.exe c:\Users\mghazanfari\Downloads\instrument1\instrument1.wav --server=10.88.1.106" but I dont know how it works with a microphone

Comment: What you describe is using the remote server, you can equally well use `parec foo.wav --server=1.2.3.4`. But it's *much* more comfortable to set up "remote" sources and sinks, and just use the local server. Have you tried to google for tutorials? Which one did you find, what worked, what didn't work?

Comment: Yes I have tried but I have found nothing which shows me how can I have an access to my mic in pulseaudio, for example I can play a music with that line code „parlay.exe Instrument.wav - - Server0.1.2.3“ but I don’t know how is that possible for a microphone.